# get all tags in an XML document using cheerio

Tags: node.js, xml, cheerio

I am trying to use `cheerio.js` to dump out all the tags in an xml document. My attempt is as follows but it seems to iterate not over every tag but every word in the document (or so it seems to me)

```js
let uniqTags = {};

const listTags = function($, tagname) {

    uniqTags[tagname] = '';

    let childNodes = $(tagname).contents()
        .map((index, element) => {
            if (element.type === 'tag') {
                return element.name
            }
        })
        .get();

    if (childNodes.length) {
        for (let i = 0, j = childNodes.length; i < j; i++) {
            listTags($, childNodes[i]);
        }
    }

}

const xml = fs.readFileSync(path.join(xmldir, xmlfile), 'utf8')

const $ = cheerio.load(xml, {
    normalizeWhitespace: true,
    xmlMode: true
});

listTags($, 'document');
```

Comment: You can get all elements with `$('*')`

Comment: yes, effectively the same my code above ('document' is the root tag). What I can't figure out is to list *only* the tag names

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @pguardiario, I was able to figure out the following code that works

```js
$('*').contents()
    .filter((index, element) => { return element.type === 'tag' })
    .map((index, element) => { return element.name } ) 
    .get();
```

running the above on almost 250K xml files inside a `fs.readdirsync()` loop took only 15 mins to generate a list of unique tags used in all the files.